# How to set visibility property of Xamarin.Forms Shell Search through Bindable Property?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am working with Xamarin.Forms(Version 5.0.0.2012) **Shell** app for Android and iOS. In the app, I have a concept in which I have to show **Shell Search** box if an user signed in, else have to hide the search box. I am following the standard MVVM pattern.

```
<Shell.SearchHandler>
        <helper:ProductSearchHandler Placeholder="Search by Title, ISBN, Publisher" TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" FontSize="Micro"
                                     ShowsResults="true" SearchBoxVisibility="{Binding TopSearchVisibility}" DisplayMemberName="Name" 
                                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProductSearchTemplate}" />
    </Shell.SearchHandler>
```

The above is the code for placing Search in my ContentPage.

**TopSearchVisibility** is my bindable property to which I bind the value from viewmodel which inherits BaseViewModel as usual.

**ProductSearchHandler** is the search handler class.

In my viewmodel,

```
// Declaration with default value
public string topSearchVisibility = "Collapsible";

public string TopSearchVisibility
{
  get { return topSearchVisibility; }
  set
  {
    topSearchVisibility = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

After getting user data from API service call, I am doing the process of show or hide the search box based on UserId, as below

```
long userID = ... from API;

if (userID > 0)
   TopSearchVisibility = "Hidden";
else
   TopSearchVisibility = "Collapsible";
```

After page loaded, **SearchBoxVisibility** property of Shell SearchHandler always binds only its default value **Expanded**. Due to that, page has the expanded view of Shell search. Shell search doesn't take the bindable property value. How to achieve my requirement with Shell search?

Comment: `SearchBoxVisibility` is an enum, not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [IValueConverter Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to convert the `string` to `SearchBoxVisibility` property.

like:

create `SearchVisibleConvert`:

```
public class SearchVisibleConvert : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SearchBoxVisibility searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Expanded;
        if (value !=null)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case "Hidden":
                    searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Hidden;
                    break;
                case "Collapsible":
                    searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Collapsible;
                    break;
                default:
                    searchBoxVisibility = SearchBoxVisibility.Expanded;
                    break;
            }
      
        }
        return searchBoxVisibility;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

use in your xaml:

```
 ...
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <controls:SearchVisibleConvert x:Key="visibleConvert" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Shell.SearchHandler>
    <helper:ProductSearchHandler Placeholder="Search by Title, ISBN, Publisher" TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" FontSize="Micro"
                                 ShowsResults="true" SearchBoxVisibility="{Binding TopSearchVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibleConvert}}" DisplayMemberName="Name" 
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProductSearchTemplate}" />
</Shell.SearchHandler>
```